# Need to draw arrows and circles on canvas without clearing the whole canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw arrows and circles on a canvas, currently the whole canvas is cleared on mousemove and mousedown or whenever the draw function is called, I am not able to draw multiple arrows and circles. Is there any other to accomplish this task?

```
heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7MRL/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack two canvases on top of each over, and draw the temporary arrows/circle on the one on top, and do the final draw on the canvas below.
This way you can clear the top canvas with no issue, and your draws 'accumulate' in the lower canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/V7MRL/5/   (updated)

I changed your draw function so it takes a 'final' flag that states wether the draw is final. 
For a final draw, lower canvas is used, for an temporary draw, upper canvas is cleared then used.

```
function draw(final) {
    var ctx = final ? context : tempContext ;
    if (final == false)   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Edit : for the issue @markE mentionned, i just handled mouseout event to cancel the draw if one is ongoing :

```
function mouseOut(eve) {
   if ( mouseIsDown ) {
      mouseIsDown = 0;
      cancelTempDraw();
   }
 }
```

with :

```
function cancelTempDraw() {
    tempContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }
```

Rq that your undo logic is not working as of now. I changed it a bit so that in draw, if the draw is final, i save the final canvas prior to drawing the latest figure to quickly have a 1-step undo. i just created a third temp canvas to/from which you copy.

Rq also that you cannot store one canvas for each stroke, or the memory will soon explode. Store the figures + their coordinates in an array if you want a full undo... or just allow 1-step undo for now.

i updated the jsfiddle link.

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  A glitch: the drawing "boogers" when you drag the mouse outside the canvas (fix==preventDefault+stopPropagation).  The only thing I feel uneasy about is that your tempCanvas is permanently on top of the results canvas so all events must be routed through the tempCanvas.  Not a problem now, but these drawing apps often evolve to include dragging and the tempCanvas would intercept events meant for the main canvas and therefore be in the way at that point. Anyway...Nice answer!  :)

Comment: Thx, yes we'll see how the O.P. react to this proposal. About the event redirection, for identically sized/scaled/... canvas it does not change that much things, since anyway we only deal with the same (x,y) coordinates whatever the canvas. In other cases, i wish js had the possibility of the WPF, where writing isHitTestVisible = false is all you have to do...

Comment: thanks! that's all I needed, you saved my life, but I would also like to know the problem that @markE pointed out